# Gad, Asher, and Dinah: absolutely, totally, and in all other ways inconceivable?

Tags: pregnancy-birth, vayeitzei

In *parashas "Vayetze"* (Gen. 29–30) we read about the birth of twelve children of *Yaakov*'s:

1. וַתַּהַר לֵאָה וַתֵּלֶד בֵּן וַתִּקְרָא שְׁמוֹ רְאוּבֵן….‏
2. וַתַּהַר עוֹד וַתֵּלֶד… וַתִּקְרָא שְׁמוֹ שִׁמְעוֹן.‏
3. וַתַּהַר עוֹד וַתֵּלֶד… קָרָא שְׁמוֹ לֵוִי.‏
4. וַתַּהַר עוֹד וַתֵּלֶד… קָרְאָה שְׁמוֹ יְהוּדָה….‏
5. וַתַּהַר בִּלְהָה וַתֵּלֶד… קָרְאָה שְׁמוֹ דָּן.‏
6. וַתַּהַר עוֹד וַתֵּלֶד… וַתִּקְרָא שְׁמוֹ נַפְתָּלִי.‏
7. וַתֵּלֶד… וַתִּקְרָא אֶת שְׁמוֹ גָּד.‏
8. וַתֵּלֶד… וַתִּקְרָא אֶת שְׁמוֹ אָשֵׁר.‏
9. וַתַּהַר וַתֵּלֶד… וַתִּקְרָא שְׁמוֹ יִשָּׂשכָר.‏
10. וַתַּהַר עוֹד לֵאָה וַתֵּלֶד… וַתִּקְרָא אֶת שְׁמוֹ זְבֻלוּן.‏
11. וְאַחַר יָלְדָה בַּת וַתִּקְרָא אֶת שְׁמָהּ דִּינָה.‏
12. וַתַּהַר וַתֵּלֶד… וַתִּקְרָא אֶת שְׁמוֹ יוֹסֵף….‏

About all of them, it mentions that the mother got pregnant ("וַתַּהַר") — except *Gad* and *Asher* (*Zilpa*'s sons) and *Dina*. Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Rashi (Bereshis 30, pasuk 10)](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8225#showrashi=true&v=10) answers on Zilpah that she was very young and the pregnancy was not visible, therefore the verse that she got pregnant was not cited.

Regarding Dinah, it could be like [Rashi (Bereshis 30, pasuk 21)](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8225#showrashi=true&v=21) that Dina should have been a son and Lea prayed that Rachel should be like the other maids so that she was converted to a girl.
In order to have a sign that this was not a natural pregnancy the Torah omitted the word "vatahar".

Update:

A nice pshat regarding dina is brought by ibn ezra(Bereshis 30, pasuk 21) that dina was actually a twin of zevulun and therefore the word vatahar does not occur. It was not a different pregnancy